# How can I make two files open automatically in a .bat file?

Tags: command-line, batch-file

The following commands are in a .bat file.

```
"C:\My folder\123.txt"
"C:\My folder\456.txt"
```

After double-clicking on the .bat file, '123.txt' will be opened but '456.txt' will not until I manually close '123.txt'.

How can I make both files opened automatically?

```
start "C:\My folder\123.txt"
start "C:\My folder\456.txt"
```

I don't know why, but if I add 'start' as shown above, both files will never be opened, just the cmd window will appear.

Comment: I don't have time to write up a proper answer, but you most likely want `START`. As a beginning, in a command line, type `start /?`. (If someone wants to take this comment and make an answer out of it, feel free to.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `start` command to tell CMD to open the file in a background process. Putting it on all lines will cause CMD to exit after opening the files; putting it on all but the last line will cause CMD to stay open until the last program (notepad or whatever your .TXT handler is) closes. The seemingly-extraneous `""` is just there to keep CMD from treating the file name as a window title instead of a command to run.

```
start "" "C:\My folder\123.txt"
start "" "C:\My folder\456.txt"
```

Comment: I don't know why, but if I add 'start' as you said, both files will never be opened, just the cmd window will appear.

Comment: @MatthewWai: Whoops, thanks. That's because Start does something derpy with commands that don't look like executables: it treats the first parameter as a title line for a new CMD window (and doesn't execute anything in that window). Putting `""` in there forces it to treat the file name as a command.